# Cleint not receive response: “No handlers could be found for message type”

Tags: nservicebus

I have a .net core service that needs to send a request via nservicebus.
I resolve IMessageSession with DI and send a request like this:

```
var response = await messageSession.Request<CreateDeviceResponse>(request);
```

In the logs I see that another service received this request and send a reply:
[image]

The problem that I never receive a response.
Client receive such errors:
[image]

I know that such an issue can occur if the client and server endpoint names are same, but I checked and I use different names

asp net mvc 4.7.2

Comment: Make sure 1) You have a class implementing `IHandleMessages<CreateDeviceReponse>` 2) NSB identifies `CreateDeviceReponse` as a command 3) Try using `IEndpointInstance` instead of `IMessageSession`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it helped to make a request inside a task:

```
Task.Run(async () => await messageSession.Request<CreateDeviceResponse>(request))
```

I still not understand what is the problem, but it works only with such implementation.
In .net core web API, it works even without Task.Run, so I believe it has something to do with the fact that I am making this request in asp net mvc 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the message isn't lost, but in the error queue.

I suggest to follow the tutorial to understand how NServiceBus works and what you need to have in place where. The [tutorials start here](https://docs.particular.net/get-started/) but an [entire learning path starts here](https://particular.net/learn/getting-started) and it explains broader, including about general concepts and architecture.

Like @tchelidze mentions, you need to have an implementation of the `IHandleMessages<CreateDeviceReponse>` interface, like is outlined [here in the tutorial](https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/nservicebus-step-by-step/2-sending-a-command/#processing-messages). Also, it doesn't matter to which endpoint you send it to. `EndpointA` can send to both `EndpointB` and `EndpointA`. What you cannot do is have two endpoints with the same name. It's like having two computers with the same name called `MachineA` and then from `MachineB` try to access files on `MachineA`. Which of the two should `MachineB` connect to? There is something else called 'competing consumer pattern', but that's of later concerns ;-)

If you need more help, feel free to ask at https://discuss.particular.net/ where more NServiceBus community members are located, as well as engineers of NServiceBus itself.

Comment: endpoint names are correct. Same configuration works with .net core, but do not works with asp net mvc 4.7.2